# Why does Amazon Linux redirects port 80 to 3000?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I'm running a NodeJS/Express app in Amazon EC2.

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
```

I start it by saying

> sudo npm start

Because it is configured in bin/www as

```
scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www" }
```

Despite setting it to 80 it always says

> Express server listening on port 3000.

Even if I force start like this sudo PORT=80 npm start, it will still say 3000. What's going on at bin/www?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use sudo npm start to start your web app.

Use sudo node app.js instead